# Large 2D world rendering in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a world made up of randomly generated blocks (black being on, white being off). When zoomed out, it essentially looks like white noise. However, instead of each block being 1 pixel, they are 40 pixels and drawn as an image texture.
My game works in a camera basis, so you can only see a fraction of the map at a time and you must move the character around to explore the rest.

Currently, I have my game simply render each image (block texture) that is in range of the canvas. This results in drawing 80-100 images every single frame. While it works fine on a desktop computer, it doesn't do very well on mobile.

Considering the map look doesn't change throughout the game, I wanted to try a different approach. I created a canvas the size of the world, which ended up being 1600x24000 pixels large. I drew all textures onto an external, hidden canvas. This was done once upon initialization. Then I would use the clipping attributes in `drawImage` to take the subsection that I needed. While it *worked*, it was extremely laggy and made things very much worse than they were before. In addition, image quality dropped to a more blurred look, which is undesirable.

Now I'm looking for ways to better go about this. So my question is, how should I go about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two more Ideas could increase your performance:

- Check if your whole world is rendered, or just the visible images (on the stage). For example double the world size and see, if it impacts the performance. It shouldn't, if you only render the relevant images.
- Use [CocoonJS](https://www.ludei.com/cocoonjs/) to compile your application. It promises to speed up your application speed by 10 times for mobile devices. But be aware that it implies some serious restrictions on your html around your canvas.

---

**obsolete answer, which assumed that the problem is caused by zooming out too far:**

In 3D graphics [Mipmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) can be used to avoid this problem. Essentially smaller images (i.e. less pixel) are used, when the object is more distant to the camera.

Maybe you can find something appropriate if you google something like *html5 canvas 2D Mipmaps*. Or you could build a simple mipmapping algorithm yourself.

But before investing the work, try how performant this approach is, by simple changing all block images, with 1x1-pixel images. Maybe your performance problem is not caused by slow rendering, as you assume. Learn to use a profiler, if it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my situation. What I mean with white noise is the general overview of what my large world would look like, assuming each pixel represented one block in this world.

Comment: Yes, I fully understood that. But your world is 1600x24000px large. On the other hand you only have a screen of e.g. 800x600px or something like that. As you already experience, it is very ineffective to draw all 1600x24000 pixels and scale them down. Instead you could precalculate what to draw on each of the 800x600 pixels, to save rendering time. My rescripted approach is one way to do that and is not about noise reduction in this case.

Comment: I don't understand how mipmapping will help me here. I am not scaling anything down. [This is an MS-Paint mock up of what my game looks like.](http://i.imgur.com/iE0HMUS.png) Each black block represents a 40x40px texture. Every single frame, I am drawing each block on screen separately. I'm looking for ways to improve this as mobile performance is not the best. I apologize in advance if I again misunderstood your solution.

Comment: But do you have the performance problems at this camera distance? as far as i understood your problem, the performance becomes critical, when you have to draw thousands of those blocks each rendering frame, because your camera zooms out!? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, at that zoom level, my Galaxy Nexus as well as Galaxy S4 running Chrome can only reach 40-45 fps. It's not terrible but I would prefer better. However, my camera does not zoom out or in, the blocks are always 40px, which gives an average of 80-100 images drawn per frame. I did a lot of testing in jsPerf and noticed the actual image size does not matter as it will be scaled up to 40px eitherway.

Comment: Ah, then I really understood your problem wrong. You have two more options, I edited them into my answer above...

Comment: Yes, I check if the block is within the canvas' bounds before drawing it. I've heard of CocoonJS, but isn't it just for native mobile apps as APKs? I want to keep my game working well for browsers too, mainly because HTML5 publishers are not interested in apks, but rather browser-ready games. I will however try CocoonJS right now to see the native performance I can get.

Comment: Basically Cocoon takes your HTML5 and wraps it into native apps for the different platforms, like cordova. And as far as I know, HTML5 game publishers are especially interested in the mobile versions of your game. How do they publish them, if not as APKs?

Comment: My experiance with CocoonJS is good so far, regarding the performance and usability. But it's really restrictive, at what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: Publishers are indeed especially interested in mobile, but mainly through the browser. They can reach many more users because no direct download/installation is required and users can just go from game to game to game trying things out.

Comment: Could you post a link to one of those sites? I'd like to try it out for myself, since I'm developing an HTML5 game too. (I'll delete this request after you posted the link, since it's not helping to answer your question).

Comment: I've haven't had my chance at it but I've seen some success stories such as [this person's blog.](http://www.truevalhalla.com/blog/) He also provides a large list of publishers, but right off the bat I have heard  [Spil Games](http://developers.spilgames.com/) is a very good publisher.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using a huge canvas, you can't be sure the renderer won't load the whole texture to render even a part of it. Since you see a huge performance drop, that might well be happening.

A few things i would do :
• try only with fillRect to see how much drawImage is to blame.
• try to set-up once and for all the context then only use drawImage with its simplest flavor :

```
var topLeft = { col:12, row : 6 }; // shift of the left-most rect (indexes)
context.save();
context.scale( scale, scale); 
for  column = 0 to columnSeenCount 
     for row = 0 to rowSeenCount
         image = the image of  ( topLeft.col + column , topLeft.row + row )
         context.drawImage( image, column, row) ;
context.restore();
```

this way you avoid to re-compute a transform matrix for every drawImage. Much less math involved for the renderer.

• if you do the drawImage by yourself, try to use only rounded coordinates, it will be faster.
• You must round also the scale to prevent artifacts. You can round on 1, but for the scale it might be too much a limit : you can easily 'round' to 0.5 or 0.25 or... by doing :

```
  var precision     = 2 ;     //  0 => floor ; 1 => at 0.5 ; 2 => 0.25 ; .... 
  var factor        = 1 << precision ;
  var roundedFigure = Math.floor( figure * factor) / factor ;
```

• if the way your application is done makes it easy to draw tile type per tile type, do it and you might win some time (you'll benefit from the fact that image in cache ).

• After that your only resort will be to use webGL or a webGL based renderer...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've done some testing and determined that drawing an image vs. simple rectangle is on average 6 fps slower on my device (Galaxy Nexus w/ Chrome) - so I would say it definitely works against performance. I'm afraid I don't quite understand your first code example. Why is the context being scaled? Other than that, it looks like you're drawing each tile individually, the same as I'm doing right now. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I've noticed mathematical operations take virtually no time compared to canvas drawing and thus rather negligible.

Comment: Assuming I caught all my non-integer coordinates, I received the same frame rate as before.

Answer (score 0):

**A couple of questions and thoughts:**

I would ditto @GameAlchemist's tip that using the clipping version of `drawImage` is slower than "blitting" a separate tile image onto the canvas.  Use separate images instead when you have such an overly large map image.

**24000 pixels is too much width to contain in any 1 image.**

It looks like you're panning horizontally.  You could slice your 24000 pixel wide image into individual images of a more reasonable size.  Each image might be 3X the screen width.  Exchange the image when the user pans beyond the edge of the current image.

**How many *unique* block image tiles are you using?**

Perhaps reduce the number of unique tiles when you detect a mobile user.  Then put each unique tile on a separate image or canvas.

**Is your map largely 1 tile type (eg. white/off)?**

If so, you could make 1 single image of a grid of enough white tiles to fill the entire canvas.  Then add black tiles where necessary.  This reduces your drawing to 1 white grid image plus any required black images.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using separate images for each tile texture. I will give split images a try. I'm not certain if I mentioned that the player always stays at the center of the screen, and thus the world moves around him. If the player sat in a corner of one of these images, I would have to draw and manage 4 others to extend the view. I'm wondering if that could cause lag spikes or simply not be worth it. I don't quite understand what you mean by unique tiles. I'm using ~15 different texture possibilities so the last options won't work.

Comment: Also, do you happen to know anything about image file types and how they affect render times? I'm currently using slightly transparent PNGs. Would switching to opaque jpgs or bmps result in a noticeable performance increase?